# custom html inside <display:column></display:cloumn>

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl, displaytag

I was wondering if its possible to render custom html inside of column tag, that is part of display table tag.

for example, i want my colum to have some dropdown list inside?

Using plain html that would be like:

```
<table>
...
<tr>
<td>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

is it possible to embed that select tag in display column? This is the demo of display column

```
<display:column property="${displayElem.name}" escapeXml="true" sortable="true" titleKey="errorHandler.${displayElem.name}" style="width: ${displayElem.length}" />
```

**EDIT:** When i try to remove property inside display column i get only html source code inside my table cell and not the html element rendering of that code.

```
 <display:column escapeXml="true"
       sortable="true" titleKey="errorHandler.${displayElem.name}"
       style="width: ${displayElem.length}" >
     <select>
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select> 
</display:column>
```

**SOLUTION:** removing escapeXml="true" attribute solved problem

```
<display:column 
       sortable="true" titleKey="errorHandler.${displayElem.name}"
       style="width: ${displayElem.length}" >
     <select>
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select> 
</display:column>
```

**SOLUTION 2 for ultimate control**

create class, extend it with decorator class and use it the display table tags

```
public class YourDecorationClass extends TableDecorator {

    public String getAction() {
        String code = "";

        code = "<select>" +
                "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>" +
                "<option value='volvo'>Saab</option>" +
                "<option value='volvo_RETRY'>Mercedes_RETRY</option>" +
                "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>";

        return code;
    }
}
```

and use decorator parameter in the display table tag

```
decorator="com.yourpackage.util.table.YourDecorationClass"
```

and of course remove escapeXml="true" from display column tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it's possible. The [documentation of the tag](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display-el%3acolumn) says:

> Displays a property of a row object inside a table. MUST be nested inside of a Table tag. The value displayed will be the results of a decorator (if any); else the property named by the 'property' attribute; or if the 'property' attribute is null, **then the results of evaluating the JSP body of the tag**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Yea, decorator might be the solution, i will investigate it. Thanks

Comment: You don't need a decorator. You just need to put what you want inside the column tag. Read what I made bold in the description.

Comment: It's not rendering html inside display table tags, i get blank cell instead when i try doing it that way.

Comment: Remove escapeXml="true", since you don't want the tag to escape the XML.

Comment: You were right those escapeXml tags were preventing it from displaying the html tags... it works now, i will accept this answer. Thanks for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 4):

You can set HTML string in Object's property. For Example in your case you can set HTML in ${displayElem.name}. It will generate a Combobox in Grid.

```
setName("<select><option value=\"JS\">John Seam<option></select>");
```

Comment: I would take this as a backup plan, at the moment i'm trying to implement table decorator, i think it might solve my problem. Thanks for the hint btw.

Comment: Welcome and If you like the hint than don't forget to accept/upvote the answer. :)

Comment: Using the decorator i got html, but its not rendered as html, just as string so i can see code in my table, i will try this, and if it works, i will upvote your answer don't worry :-)